# Import Flash CS4 Project to Flex Builder 3

Tags: flash, flex3, flash-cs4, flexbuilder, import

I'm fairly deep with Flash CS4 project. I've got Flex Builder now, and I want to use it. I have .fla file and couple of Classes. .fla file is actually one ActionScript Frame document with Library items with linkages. I want to do .fla file skinning in Flash later, but develop with Flex. 
Can you help me with importing. I've never used Flex Builder before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your .as classes in Flex Builder (or Flashdevelop 3 which is actually a better coding environment than Flex Builder). I don't think you can edit .fla files in Flex. You can do pure as3 projects in Flex if you wish.

Comment: Why is Flash Develop better environment? Can you control .Fla with FD?

Comment: No. But Flash Develop is has a more faster and responsive code editor than Flex is, which kind of slow. 
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4965
Try it out yourself.

Comment: I'm working with FD for two days now, great tool, I couldn't set up FB but FD took mi 10min.